# A replacement to "\mathbbm{1}" with type-1 fonts

Tags: fonts, symbols

I use the symbol "\mathbbm{1}" to produce a nice-looking "1" digit. But, then my PDF contains a "Type-3" font, which is not allowed by my publisher.
Is there a replacement that does not use a type-3 font?

Comment: The STIX fonts contain blackboard bold digits, although the style is different from that of the font you are now using.

Comment: Does your publisher accept documents made with OpenType math fonts?

Comment: @Davislor good question. I had to submit a month ago, so I just put a usual "1" instead of the fancy 1, and submitted. I do not know whether OpenType fonts are accepted.

Comment: The question specifies Type-1, but this is one of many, many problems that can be solved going forward by switching to `unicode-math`, since all up-to-date OpenType math fonts support `\mathbb{1}`. If, that is, a publisher allows it.

Comment: @Davislor thanks, I will check this out the next time I run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [doublestroke](https://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke) package provides  blackboard fonts in type 1 format, including the `\mathds{1}` that you are looking for.

It does not exactly look like those of `bbm`, but could likely be used as a drop in replacement in your case

Answer (score 10):

Another possibilty is use the package `bbold` symbol font to get a similar `\mathds{1}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{1}$

\end{document}
```

Using `dsfont` you will have:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the use of the package `bbold` will also change other mathbb characters you might have used (set N of natural numbers, R, C, etc.)

Comment: @Karlo I agree with you; it always depends on what you want to create. In my case I have a lot of packages loaded for a personal project and I didn't have any problems.